# Get facebook access token with page_managment permission for specific user without full review of the app

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-access-token

Is it possible to get an access token (from the SDK not the api explorer [ex: Login Form]) with page_management permission for some specific user (the future possible client of the app) without passing the full Facebook review process. I need this, because the app is not finished yet, and the client has to approve it. I don’t care if the token expires in 1 hour or less.
But i don't want to send the client to the api graph explorer.

Comment: Only if you add them to the app in the tester role. (But for that they would still need to have their account verified as a developer, AFAIK)

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot @CBroe, what you propose is enough for me.